# Get the first children folder(s) on a selected folder

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to just return the children folder of a specfic folder in Google Drive SDK. If I have the following structure

```
 mainfolder -> //id:1234567
     testing1 ->
         actuafile.png
         testing.png
     testing2 ->
         banass.png
     testing3 ->
```

My testing code so far but it print all the files, it includes the `testing1,testing2..` and the `actuafile.png,testing.png...`

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
  'q': "'1234567' in parents"
});

request.execute(function(r){
    console.log(r);
});
```

How can I limit to just the first folder(s)?

Answer (score 2):

Make your search query:

mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '123456' in parents

Answer (score 2):

+1 Jay's answer. However ...

The fact that `actualfile.png,testing.png` are included, implies that they also have 123456 as a parent. ie your structure is not as you described it, but

```
  mainfolder -> //id:1234567
     L_ testing1 
     L_ actuafile.png
     L_ testing.png
     L_ testing2 
     L_ banass.png
     L_ testing3
```

Just double check that the parentage of your files is what you think it is. It may well be that actualfile.png has both mainfolder **and** testing1 as parents, ie

```
  mainfolder -> //id:1234567
     L_ testing1 
     L___L_ actuafile.png
     L___L_ testing.png
     L_ testing2 
     L___L_ banass.png
     L_ testing3
```

I do that in one of my apps, so it's not wrong. Just be sure.